# URLs not working on Nginx + Django. Everything goes to the welcome page

Tags: django, url, nginx

I know there are other answers concerning this topic, and I've been through them all and couldn't solve my problem!

Basically I have the same problem described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026314/django-and-nginx-urls-are-all-the-same). No matter what I put after / in the URL, I always get the welcome page.

Here's the urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^lists/$', 'glic.lists.index'),
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

and here's the Nginx config file:

```
server {
listen   80;
listen   [::]:80 default ipv6only=on;

server_name  glic.bauleo.com.br;

access_log  /home/glic.bauleo.com.br/log/access.log;
error_log  /home/glic.bauleo.com.br/log/error.log;

location /admin_media {
    alias /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/media/;
}

location /media {
    alias /home/glic.bauleo.com.br/web/;
}

location / {
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8080;
    fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
    fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
    fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
    fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

    fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO          $fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
    fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
    fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
    fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;

    fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
    fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

    fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
    fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
    fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
    fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
    fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;
}
}
```

Also, here's the INSTALLED_APPS I forgot

You can go to http://glic.bauleo.com.br to test it. I've spent 5 hours reading articles and posts and trying to fix this but I couldn't find the solution.
BTW, I'm running Ubuntu 10.10 x86 on a VPS.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
Forgot to post the INSTALLED_APPS:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
   'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'lists',
 )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

most probably you do not have anything in `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`

at least there are no 'django.contrib.admin' and 'glic' apps.

Comment: Oh yeah, forgot to add the INSTALLED_APPS! Actually everything's seems to be ok. I've put the INSTALLED_APPS in the original question.

Comment: could you check and movie 'fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8080;' after all 'fastcgi_param' (end of the 'location /')

Comment: I moved the fastcgi_pass directive to the end of "location /" but I still can't get things to work. Something I noticed is that if I keep refreshing the page sometimes I get an "ImproperlyConfigured at /admin/" exception with the value "Put 'django.contrib.admin' in your INSTALLED_APPS setting in order to use the admin application." even though it's actually there. I'm beginning to think that something is broken, maybe I'll reinstall everything, including the OS.

Comment: first - make sure that all nginx workers are restarted, second - remove all *.pyc files then restart django

Comment: Hell yeah! Removed all the .pyc files and it worked! :) Thanks a lot, I was just about to install everything from scratch!